# Hide an element and it's space and notify the app so it displays other content with React

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

Hello everyone. Sorry if this is a stupid question or something really easy. I'm new on the javascript scene.

I'm trying to develop a React Application.
My app consists of two things: a **loader**, which is a react component, and the **app content**, which is hidden by default.

The loader is just a simple HTML and CSS animation, which runs a task asynchronously, and when the task finishes, it's assigned a class that makes it fade out.

As the Loader is just hidden, it continues to take space, and as it is a separate React Component, I don't know how would I notify my app that the Loader component has finished.

So basically what I want is the loader to be completely gone, so it doesn't continue taking space while being invisible and the app content to appear when the loader finishes. This seems like an extremely simple task but I haven't been able to figure out how.

How can I achieve this?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

## My code

**App Component**

```
function App() {
    componentDidMount() {
        Secure()
    }

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <Loader task={test()}/>
          <div className="App-content">
            <h1>Welcome to GitChain</h1>
          </div>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
}
```

**Loader component**

```
class Loader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount(callback) {
      ;(async () => {
      await this.props.task
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      })();
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <div className={this.state.loading ? "sk-folding-cube" : "sk-folding-cube completed"}>
          <div className="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

**App.css**

```
.App {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont;
    font-weight: bold;
 }

.App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
    height: 40vmin;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.App-header {
    background-color: #060606;
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: calc(10px + 2vmin);
    color: white;
}

.App-link {
    color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
    from {
      transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    to {
      transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.App-content {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control what `App` renders (if I understood you correctly based on "...and the app content to appear when the loader finishes.") based on `Loader` you would need to move the loading state to `App` level.

You can do something like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = { loading: true };
      this.switchLoadingState = this.switchLoadingState.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
    // componentDidMount is available in class components only
      Secure()
    }

    switchLoadingState() {
      this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading })
    }

    render() {
      const { loading } = this.state

      return (
        <div className="App">
          { loading && (
            <header className="App-header">
              <Loader task={test()} loading={loading} switchLoadingState={this.switchLoadingState} />
              <div className="App-content">
                <h1>Welcome to GitChain</h1>
              </div>
            </header>)
          }
        </div>
    );
    }

}

class Loader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount(callback) {
      ;(async () => {
      await this.props.task
      this.props.switchLoadingState();
      })();
    }

    render() {
      const { loading } = this.props
      return (
        <div className={loading ? "sk-folding-cube" : "sk-folding-cube completed"}>
          <div className="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I needed, but when I try to run your code, I keep getting this error on `const switchLoadingState = () => this.setState({ loading: !this.state.loading })`: `Parsing error: Unexpected Token` at the space between `!this.state.loading` and `}`. Sorry to bother you

Comment: can you try now, I've rewritten that function as a ES5 function

Comment: also, please take a look at https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-black-b0rzj for further clarification

Answer (score 1):

you can return null in the render method, so it won't render anything.

```
class Loader extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { loading: true };
    }

    componentDidMount(callback) {
      ;(async () => {
      await this.props.task
      this.setState({ loading: false });
      })();
    }

    render() {

      if (!this.state.loading) {
        return null;
      }

      return (
        <div className={this.state.loading ? "sk-folding-cube" : "sk-folding-cube completed"}>
          <div className="sk-cube1 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube2 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube4 sk-cube"></div>
          <div className="sk-cube3 sk-cube"></div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes, thanks, this is similar to what I wanted, but this immediately hides the loader, so it doesn't make the animation, but that isn't much of a problem. So now, how can I notify my app the Loader stopped rendering so it can display other content? Sorry to bother you

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to wrap your whole Loader component in a condition like this

```
{this.state.loading && <Loader task={test()}/>}
```

This will only show the loader component if `this.state.loading` is true.

Comment: Thanks, this works. And now, how can I notify my main app that the loader isn't rendering so it can display the `App-content` div? Sorry to bother you

Comment: I would handle this in the parent component example in the parent component create a function `setLoading = (val) => {this.setState({loding:val})}` and pass it along in the loader componont like `<Loader showLoaderHandler={this.setLoading}} task={task()}>` then in the loader component  call `this.props.showLoaderHandler(false)` when you want to hide the loader.